# Formula for max volume of rectangular bag

Tags: geometry

I'd like a formula for a bag made of two flat equal sized rectangles (e.g. a freezer bag). Assume no stretching, and perfect flexibility. Volume in terms of a and b, the dimensions of the bag when flat.

Thanks

Comment: It's not homework. I haven't tried anything, it's beyond me but I'm guessing could be done using some combination of spheres and cones. A good approximation would be fine, say +/- 5%

Comment: As a starting point, a sphere maximises volume for a given surface area, so if we define $r$ to be such that $4\pi r^2 = 2ab$, we can't possibly do better than $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. I suspect that in general this is a very loose bound.

Comment: $\sqrt\frac{ab}{2\pi} = r$, so an upper bound is $\frac{4}{3}\pi(\frac{ab}{2\pi})^\frac{3}{2}$ which simplifies to $\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}a^3b^3}$. I suspect this problem of being *hard*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem is difficult.  It certainly is difficult if you started with two congruent disks rather than two congruent rectangles.  The disks problem is sometimes known as the *Mylar Balloon problem*.  See, e.g., "The Mylar Balloon Revisited," 2003, *Amer. Math. Monthly* ([JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/3647797)).
See also Igor Pak's 2006 paper, "Inflating polyhedral surfaces" ([CiteSeer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.71.9361)).

          [image: Mylar Balloon]